# badblocks utility keeps reporting "invalid last block"

Tags: linux, badblocks

I'm trying to run `badblocks` on a drive with a single partition.  The drive contains a FreeBSD file system on it.

I boot up using a Linux live USB drive.  The drive is unmounted.  The output of `fdisk -l` is:

```
   Device  Boot     Start          End    Id     System
/dev/sda1     *        63   976773167+    a5     FreeBSD
```

So I run:

```
# badblocks -v /dev/sda1
```

And it says:

```
badblocks: invalid last block - /dev/sda1
```

I can't find any useful information about this.  Am I using the `badblocks` utility correctly here?  Or is this an indication that something is wrong with the drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't an indication something is wrong with the drive. You are getting this error because badblocks is accepting /dev/sda1 as the last-block argument instead of accepting it as the device.

The syntax in your question looks correct to me. Try specifying the last-block argument after the device:
`badblocks -v /dev/sda1 976773167`

If that doesn't work, try adding the first-block to that as well:
`badblocks -v /dev/sda1 976773167 63`

Just to assure you that this does not indicate something is wrong with your drive, here is the output when I add an invalid last-block argument "nope":

> sudo badblocks -v /dev/sdb1 nope
>   badblocks: invalid last block - nope

---

Here is an example from my bash history of the last time I used badblocks (sudo access is required to access these drives on my system):
`sudo badblocks -v /dev/sdb1`

Output:

> Checking blocks 0 to 976751967
>   Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):

If I cancel the process after awhile with Ctrl+C the output is:

> Interrupted at block 7470720

Here is the syntax to resume the process (see `man badblocks`):
**badblocks -v device  [ last-block ] [ first-block ]**

The "last-block" is the last block to be read on the device and "first-block" is where it should start reading. Example:
`sudo badblocks -v /dev/sdb1 976751967 7470720`

Output:

> Checking blocks 7470720 to 976751967 Checking for bad blocks
>   (read-only test):

Comment: And about `sudo badblocks -v  /media/myUser/NewVol1/` ?  same error and no way to be **automatic**, like your `badblocks -v /dev/sdb1`

Answer (score 1):

The badblocks command on modern disk drive hardware is hardly worth the effort these days.  This is because the drive controller board identifies bad blocks internally and substitutes from an initially allocated of "spare" blocks for automatic replacement.  If you have run out of these spare blocks and are having bad block problems, I'd STRONGLY suggest disk replacement as the hardware is going bad.

If you are looking to find the health of the drive, most of the modern drives support the SMART drive interface to report the disk health.  There are many utilities out there that status and present this information on disk health out there.  Try one of these.

Comment: What about SD Cards? Maybe testing them with bad blocks could be worth the price?

Answer (score 0):

You copied your command from a web page. The dash was replaced with some different dash character in -v. (a bit longer than the normal dash) Type the command or fix it somehow.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error despite using correct syntax and you are using large disks (e.g. several TB) with small block size (e.g. 512 bytes) then you might be running into a `badblocks` limitation of using 32-bits for block numbers.

As a workaround you can use a bigger block. To find the minimal block size that `badblocks` can work with you can simply run `badblocks` with different values for `-b` and without start/end block. If you get an error like this

> badblocks: Value too large for defined data type invalid end block: must be 32-bit value

then try increasing the block size (e.g. `-b 512` to `-b 1024` or `-b 2048`) until it works. With this you use some resolution, but it's better than nothing.

You might also use `ddrescue` at this point, or contact maintaner of `badblocks` to fix the problem in the next version.